# Issues with getDrawable compatibilty

Tags: java, android

This is the line in question. I have it the same way the textbook lists it, but am having issues converting the line to `ContextCombat` since `getDrawable()` has been deprecated.

```
buttonItem.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(painting.getId()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);`. This will return a styled Drawable as instructed by your Activity's theme. Your code would be more or less as shown below:

```
buttonItem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), painting.getId()));
```

**NOTE:** I'm assuming that `painting.getId()` returns the resource id for the image you want to set as your button's drawable. Also, if you are doing this inside an Activity, you should use the keyword `this` instead of `getActvity()`.

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of that error at least. When I attempt to launch it in debugger mode I get the error "Unfortunately, Renaissance Paintings has stopped."

Comment: Is that the only error message you got? Since I don't have access to your program's source code, I need more information in order to understand the problem.

Comment: It's working now! It turns out the other issue was that there was a book typo saying linearList instead of linearLayout. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you managed to make it work! If the answer I gave helped solving your problem I would be glad if you could mark it as your "accepted answer" (by clicking on the grayed out "tick" icon to the left of it).

Comment: I really appreciate it!